# Spring Boot Keycloak refresh token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, keycloak

I have a Spring Boot server which manages authentication via Keycloak. I managed to set up a working login flow, but I now have problems in refreshing the token (mostly because the documentation is quite simply non-existent).
The access token Keycloak provides expires after 5 minutes, so I would like to expose an endpoint to allow clients to refresh the token. What I do in the login phase is return to the client the accessToken and the refreshToken. The problem is that I don't know how to use the refresh token once the access one is expired (see comment in `refreshLogin` function).
Current code is attached.

**AuthenticationController**

```kotlin
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
@Validated
class AuthenticationController(private val authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
    @PostMapping("/API/login")
    fun login(@RequestBody @Valid loginDTO: LoginDTO): JwtDTO {
        return authenticationService.login(loginDTO) ?: throw GenericException()
    }

    @PostMapping("/API/refreshLogin/{refreshToken}")
    fun refreshLogin(@PathVariable refreshToken: String): JwtDTO {
        return authenticationService.refreshLogin(refreshToken) ?: throw GenericException()
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationService**

```kotlin
interface AuthenticationService {
    fun login(loginDTO: LoginDTO): JwtDTO?

    fun refreshLogin(refreshToken: String): JwtDTO?
}
```

**AuthenticationServiceImpl** (implements *AuthenticationService*)

```kotlin
@Service
class AuthenticationServiceImpl: AuthenticationService {
    @Value("\${keycloak.address}")
    private lateinit var keycloakAddress: String

    override fun login(loginDTO: LoginDTO): JwtDTO? {
        val keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://$keycloakAddress")
            .realm("wa2-products")
            .clientId("wa2-products-client")
            .username(loginDTO.email)
            .password(loginDTO.password)
            .build()

        return try {
            val tokenSet = keycloak.tokenManager().grantToken()
            JwtDTO(tokenSet.token, tokenSet.refreshToken)
        } catch (e: NotAuthorizedException) {
            null
        }
    }

    override fun refreshLogin(refreshToken: String): JwtDTO? {
        val keycloak = KeycloakBuilder.builder()
            .serverUrl("http://$keycloakAddress")
            .realm("wa2-products")
            .clientId("wa2-products-client")
            // how to pass the refresh token here??
            .build()

        return try {
            val tokenSet = keycloak.tokenManager().grantToken()
            JwtDTO(tokenSet.token, tokenSet.refreshToken)
        } catch (e: NotAuthorizedException) {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

**JwtDTO**

```kotlin
data class JwtDTO(
    val jwtAccessToken: String,
    val refreshToken: String
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A refresh token is requested by the client with the `offline_access` scope. This refresh token is then used by the OAuth2 client **to which it was delivered** using the `refresh_token` flow. And this has nothing specific to Spring or Keycloak.

It is the job of OAuth2 client implementations (Spring Security proposes one) to store tokens and **handle OAuth2 flows** (`authorization_code` flow with which you get the initial tokens for a user and then `refresh_token` to renew this tokens).

You should not try to write the flow by yourself and **you should certainly not exchange users credentials or refresh tokens between your front-ends and your Spring back-ends**. This `/API/login` and `/API/refreshLogin` should exist on neither an OAuth2 client nor an OAuth2 resource server. Additionally, users should not input their credentials in your frontend, this is not how OAuth2 `authorization_code` flow works.

#### PS

When using OpenID it is generally considered a good idea to have some basic knowledge about OAuth2 and OpenID. You should get some more background about OAuth2 actors and their responsibilities (`client`, `resource server`, `authorisation server` and `resource owner`), as well as OAuth2 flows (a minimum of `authorization_code`, `client_credentials` and `refresh_token`).

You should also learn why mobile and Javascript based (React, Angular, Vue, etc.) front-ends would make pretty unsafe OAuth2 clients, and why it is recommended to:

- avoid the usage of "public" clients
- hide tokens from mobile and web apps

In the case of your React app running on port 3000, requests should be authorized with sessions on a Spring backend configured as an OAuth2 client. It is not recommended any more to configure it as public OAuth2 client, using tokens to query resource servers directly. If you are using Next.js, the OAuth2 client on the back-end could be the "node" side of the app (but this really is optional and probably more scalable when implemented with `spring-cloud-gateway`).

Resource servers should be hidden behind a confidential client replacing session cookie with an access token kept in session before forwarding a request to it.

Understanding correctly CORS and CSRF is also required to write a decent security conf (one that does not implement wide breaches).

What you are doing here looks like an inventory of worst practices. You should probably pause your implementation and get some education.

Comment: Thank you for the time you took to answer.
To give some context, this code is from a university project where we were told to "use Keycloak", that's it. No information on how or why (or how it generally works), so we followed guides online similar to what I ended up doing.
I'll try and better understand what you wrote, I have no doubt things should be done very differently, we do know that in this (poor) course we're doing things without any clue (we try our best but clearly sometimes we make mistakes).
At the very least this is not and will never be production code, but again thanks.

Comment: You could find useful info in my tutorials README https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials In addition to the concepts I link, you should have look at the BFF tutorial (even if I use Angular there: as front-end is not OAuth2, all you need to understand from it is how login is initiated)